# seeding random generator /printing the max value

Tags: c++

My homework is to find the largest of 15 random numbers ,find the maximum value, find the number of times the maximum appears in the list, and seed the random number generator with the time of day.

I must use a for loop to do this.
Upon each pass through the loop, I must do the following:
•   Generate a random number between 10 and 20, assign it to the random number variable, and print it.

•   Check to see if it is larger than the maximum.  If it is a new maximum, assign to maximum.  If the number is equal to the maximum add to count accordingly.

•   Upon exiting the loop, print the maximum and the number of times it appears in the list.

My problem is, how do I print the maximum number from the loop, how do I seed the generator with the time of day, and what exactly am I to do?

Thanks in advance.

code so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int random_x;
    int k;
    int max;
    int num = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int t = 0; t<15; t++)
    {
        int random_x;
        random_x = rand() % 100;
        printf("The random numbers are: %d\n", random_x);
    }

    max = INT_MIN;
    for (k = 1; k <= 10; k++) 
    {
        int random_x;
        random_x = rand() % 100;
        if (num > max) max = num;
    } 
    printf("The largest number of the 15 numbers entered was %d\n\n", max);
}
```

Comment: Look at the second loop again. Look at the use of the variable `random_x`. Look at the use of the variable `num`. Think about thoses uses for a while.

Comment: are you looking for C++ answers because this is written as C? In C++ we would use the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header

Comment: c++ help. This code is as my instructor has showed me.

Comment: So the major issue answering this question is that it's your homework, if we answer it we'd be doing your homework for you. That would significantly detract from what the homework is trying to teach you. @JoachimPileborg has already given you a good hint of where to start.

Comment: Does your code work?   see [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

using namespace std;

int main () {
    // srand seeds the random generator,
    // and here we're passing it the time as well
    srand (time (NULL));

    auto max = 0;
    auto maxCount = 0;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        auto n = rand () % 10 + 10;

        // comment this out after you're sure things are working
        cout << "n: " << n << endl;

        if (n > max) {
            max = n;
            maxCount = 0;
        }

        if (n == max) {
            maxCount++;
        }
    }

    cout << "max: " << max << endl << "max occurred " << maxCount << " times" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is C++11 so you'll need a C++11 compiler.
With g++ on Linux compile it with: `g++ -std=c++11 -o randtest.i386 randtest.cpp`